# Provide intellisense for custom language in Visual Studio when caret is in virtual space

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm developing an extension for visual studio that provides intellisense for a custom language.
So far I started with this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Ook_Language_Integration), more specifically this [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/master/Ook_Language_Integration/C%23/Intellisense/CompletionSource.cs).
Sadly, this sample (and all others I've seen on the internet) has problems with virtual spaces. When the cursor is placed in such a virtual space, the `triggerPoint` that is obtained with `session.GetTriggerPoint(snapshot)` is set back to the non-virtual position before the cursor (and as far as I know, `SnapshotPoint` can only represent non-virtual positions) which leads to a wrongly positioned intellisense window:
[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this?
I tried to understand how it is done in the roslyn extension, but that code is horrific complicated (it seems like ~5k LOC and ~100 classes just for autocompletion).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but that screenshot really brought a smile to my face.  Thanks.

Comment: I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/issues/15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I managed to find the [code](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures/Implementation/Intellisense/Completion/Controller.cs,164) that is responsible for that in roslyn:

```
if (this.TextView.Caret.Position.VirtualBufferPosition.IsInVirtualSpace)
{
    // Convert any virtual whitespace to real whitespace by doing an empty edit at the caret position.
    _editorOperationsFactoryService.GetEditorOperations(TextView).InsertText("");
}
```